# TCP/IPv6 socket connection failed in C

Tags: c, sockets, virtual-machine, ipv6

I am trying to run a simple TCP/IPv6 client/server on 2 Centos7 VMs.

The 2 VMs are NATed, and on the host-only adapter in VirtualBox.

I ran an IP command on the server's VM and copied the address of interface `enp0s8`, which is **"fe80::1061:a71b:5d99:c790"**.

The server runs fine, but when I run the client, I get a connection failed error.

This is a server:

```c
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define PORT 7777

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{ 
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread; 
    struct sockaddr_in6 address; 
    int opt = 1; 
    int addrlen = sizeof(address); 
    char buffer[1024] = {0}; 
    char *hello = "Hello from server"; 
       
    // Creating socket file descriptor 
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) 
    { 
        perror("socket failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
       
    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, 
                                                  &opt, sizeof(opt))) 
    { 
        perror("setsockopt"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    address.sin6_family = AF_INET6; 
    address.sin6_addr = in6addr_any; 
    address.sin6_port = htons( PORT ); 

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,  
                                 sizeof(address))<0) 
    { 
        perror("bind failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 

    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0) 
    { 
        perror("listen"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 

    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,  
                       (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0) 
    { 
        perror("accept"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 

    valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024); 
    printf("%s\n",buffer ); 
    send(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 ); 
    printf("Hello message sent\n"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

And this is the client:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define PORT 7777 
   
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{ 
    int sock = 0, valread; 
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
    char *hello = "Hello from client"; 
    char buffer[1024] = {0}; 

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) 
    { 
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 
   
    serv_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6; 
    serv_addr.sin6_port = htons(PORT); 

    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form 
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET6, "fe80::1061:a71b:5d99:c790", &serv_addr.sin6_addr)<=0)  
    { 
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 
   
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    { 
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 

    send(sock , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 ); 
    printf("Hello message sent\n"); 
    valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024); 
    printf("%s\n",buffer ); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You do not NAT IPv6. Also, link-local addresses require you to use the Zone ID.

Comment: On the server, `setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT)` is wrong, you need to call `setsockopt()` for each socket option individually. On the client, `serv_addr` is declared as `sockaddr_in` but it needs to be `sockaddr_in6` instead. On both sides, `read()` is not outputting a null-terminated string (and neither party is ending a null-terminator anyway), but you are treating the `buffer` like it is null-terminated (which it is in your example, but this is the wrong way to handle it). You should pass the return value of `read()` to `printf()`, eg: `printf("%.*s\n", valread, buffer);`

Comment: Thank you so much !
@RemyLebeau i cahnged the `sockaddr_in` to `sockaddr_in6` but the problem seem to appear in the only in the client side. Its probably an addressing issue.
@RonMaupin  When i put both the Sever and Client in the same host and changed the `inet_pton(AF_INET6, "fe80::1061:a71b:5d99:c790", &serv_addr.sin6_addr)` to
`(inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &serv_addr.sin6_addr)` it worked fine and i received the messages from both sides. What should i do to communicate between 2 VMs using IPv6, knowing that i am able to `ping -6` between them.

Comment: The link-local addresses are in the `fe80::/10` address range. Using link-local addressing requires you to use the [Zone ID](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4007#section-11.2). The specific format of the Zone ID varies by OS and version.